# iphone UITableView creation dynamically

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to create multiple UITableViews dynamically. Depending on the selection on the previous view controller, the current one should decide how many UITableViews are needed.

e.g. If the user chooses to see 2 different types of Data (height and weight) I want to show 2   tables with that information. If he selects 3 (height, weight and waist size) I want to show 3 tables.

Can you please help.

Comment: You can do that.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create as many UITableViews as you want, e.g. with

```
UITableView *tbl1 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,200)];
[self.view addSubview:tbl1];
[tbl1 release];
UITableView *tbl2 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,200)];
[self.view addSubview:tbl2];
[tbl2 release];
...
```

However, i'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish, you could try to provide a sketch or a wireframe. Are you looking into including more tableviews in one view, or rather in separate screens?

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure out how to incorporate the design. It was  one table cell selection driving the display of the other 2 tables. I had to include conditions within didSelect for the master table and manipulated the view to display the next table.